# A Sane and Simple Image Button for WPF With Triggers?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've looked at some other Stack Overflow Questions, but none seem to give a simple solution to this.

I have a button that should be an image. On MouseOver the image changes, same as with MouseClick.

I have the code for MouseOver here:

```
    <Button Name="btnNext" Grid.Row="3" Padding="15 3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="OnButtonClick" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Image Width="90" Height="90">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/Button1_A.png" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/Button1_B.png" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

This seems like an awful lot of code for something that, I feel, should be relatively simple. Is there a simpler solution that I am missing?

Comment: In Silverlight I would just set the `Button.Content` to be the image.  This would cause the button to appear on the face of the button.  If I don't want the button face, I typically use a HyperlinkButton.

Comment: cadrell0: From what I can tell, WPF doesn't have a HyperlinkButton ):

Comment: That really doesn't look like "too much" code.  XAML is very verbose.

Comment: cadrell0: Sounds like a slight understatement :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... you define a control template - and the main benefit for defining a control template is making it reusable. Templates are rarely defined inline the element, but typically in a resource dictionary (or even in the theme dictionary, so you can have a different template for each team). If you had 3 buttons, you could use it templates like that:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ct" TargetType="Button">
        <Border>
            <Image Width="90" Height="90">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/a.png" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/b.png" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="btnPrev" Padding="15,3" Click="OnButtonClick" Template="{StaticResource ct}" />
    <Button Name="btnNext" Padding="15,3" Click="OnButtonClick" Template="{StaticResource ct}" />
    <Button Name="btnFinish" Padding="15,3" Click="OnButtonClick" Template="{StaticResource ct}" />
</StackPanel>
```

There are still some opportunistic shortcuts you can take:

1. If you aren't doing anything with Border, you can remove it. It contributes nothing.
2. There is no need to modify the Button.Template and have a ControlTemplate - remove these two lines

You will end up with (6 lines shorter):

```
<Button Name="btnNext" Padding="15,3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="OnButtonClick">
    <Image Width="90" Height="90">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/a.png" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/resources/b.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Finally, if you want to optimize your program to number of lines - trading off engineering practices - you'll have a shorter program with MouseEnter and MouseLeave events. With 3 lines of code for each event handler in the code behind, and 3 lines of code for the <Button><Image/><Button> int the XAML file, you are with 9 lines of code.